# Objects Not Visible Within S3 Bucket for GroundTruth Labeling Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

I am currently creating a GroundTruth Labeling job, and am following the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FPI6KjDlCI&t=210s
I have created the same bucket `ground-truth-example-labeling-job` and uploaded jpg files within the bucket. Within this tutorial, under Select S3 bucket or resource, they were able to go within the S3 Bucket and access the jpg files inside.

However, I am able to go inside the `ground-truth-example-labeling-job` bucket, but no jpg files are visible for me to select. The entire bucket is empty with nothing to select.

Is this a permissions settings problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select the files.

But if you have a folder within a bucket then you can select that folder which consists of the input data.

In the video they selected the bucket but not the files.

Comment: One more thing I that I did to fix the issue is by trying various regions. Apparently, the GroundTruth labeling only works for certain regions